# A bit lost with Rails 3 and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I'm working on my first rails application using
Rails 3.2.8
ruby 1.9.3p392

It's very entertaining and I've been learning a lot. I remain though very much confused on how to use javascript in my application.

I need it to do all sort of things like unobstrusive ajax calls, browser js function calls  (for example I'm struggling now to add the binding for spinedit: https://github.com/geersch/bootstrap-spinedit ).

On top of this (actually simplifying rather than messing up) I'm using simple_form, haml and bootstrap.

I've studied lots of documents only to find often that they referred to rails 2, and were not actual any more.

Is there any nice resource where I could finally place everything in order, and get to have decent understanding of how it works?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest watching the [RailsCasts - Understand the Asset Pipeline](http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline). (basically it's in `app/assets/javascripts/`)

Comment: Thanks that was useful, but I need also something more specific to javascript.

Comment: basically this works the same. Just put a file in your `app/assets/javascripts/` folder